# Figuring out high cpu usage queries in prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I am in charge of managing a prometheus cluster for multiple teams. Average CPU utilization is 0.6 of 4 allocated CPU cores. However sometimes prometheus is maxing out the CPu at 4 cores for severel mintues or sometimes even hours.

I assume the high CPU usage is being caused by Grafana dashboards which run a lot of (inefficient) queries. Since each time has several grafana dashboards I am having a hard time figuring out what dashboard or even query is causing the high CPU usage on my prometheus cluster. The even bigger problem is, that this causes all other dashboards to be very slow because the prometheus instance can not answer queries in a timely manner.

**The question**

How could I figure out what queries are consuming a lot of CPU usage or how could I limit the CPU usage for queries / teams?

Comment: Have you figured it out? I'm experiencing similar issues.

Comment: I limited the number of max samples which has helped me in that case. Just recently they closed that issue in the prometheus repository without offering a solution for that, which is really sad: https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/4923 . You can also take a look at the prometheus operator which deploy prometheus instances with "best practices", but now I am experiencing out of memory issues haha. Best luck!

Answer (score 0):

Outdated, but still able to google.
Right now you can enable queries logging
https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/pull/6520/files#diff-17f1012e0c2fbd9bcd8dff3c23b18ff4b6676eef3beca6f8a3e72e6a36633334L68-R71

```
global:
...
  # File to which PromQL queries are logged.
  # Reloading the configuration will reopen the file.
  [ query_log_file: <string> ]
```